# Paypal standard buttons not returning transaction variables

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox, paypal-sandbox

I'm using PayPal standard buttons in the sandbox environment, but it's driving me bad, I'm using the return custom variable with the rm set to 2, so PayPal should return back to my return URL along with a $_POST array populated with the transaction info, what happens is that it return to my return URL but with an empty $_POST !!
What is really driving me mad is that sometimes return with a populated $_POST array, for the same scenario !!!
Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Auto and PDT enabled in the account?  If you have PDT enabled turn this off.  Did you try testing with auto return disabled in the account as well?  Try both of these, and see if you get the data returned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.What do you mean my PDT ?

Comment: See if you have it turned on.  You can follow the steps listed at the at this link to see if it is turned on, the steps are for setting it up.  However, you just need to see if it is turned on, and if you do you can turn it off.  https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/747/kw/PDT